# Multiple SELECT statements into a single JSON

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I'm convinced this must be answered somewhere but for the life of me I just can't seem to find anything no matter how much I change my search phrases.

I need to select data from two completely independent tables and export the information to JSON.  In this case, they're both 1 record in each table.

If I select just 1 at a time and export to JSON, they're 1 record, but when I join the two single records in SQL and then export to JSON, they're 1 record arrays.

**Just 1 record SQL Input:**

```
DECLARE @Json nvarchar(max) = 
(   
    SELECT 'Data1' AS [Data1], 'Data2' AS [Data2]

    FOR JSON PATH
    , INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
    , WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
);

SELECT @Json;
GO
```

**Just 1 record JSON Output (note there's no array):**

```
{
  "Data1": "Data1",
  "Data2": "Data2"
}
```

**2 record SQL Input:**

```
DECLARE @Json nvarchar(max) = 
(   
    SELECT
    (
        SELECT 'Data1' AS [Data1], 'Data2' AS [Data2]

        FOR JSON PATH
        , INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
    ) AS [Part1]
    ,
    (
        SELECT 'Text1' AS [Text1], 'Text2' AS [Text2]

        FOR JSON PATH
        , INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
    ) AS [Part2]

    FOR JSON PATH
    , WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
);

SELECT @Json;
GO
```

**2 record JSON Output (note the inclusion of arrays):**

```
{
  "Part1": [
    {
      "Data1": "Data1",
      "Data2": "Data2"
    }
  ],
  "Part2": [
    {
      "Text1": "Text1",
      "Text2": "Text2"
    }
  ]
}
```

I "think" that WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER is the correct attribute to add which will resolve this but as soon as I add that, I get the entire record as a string:

```
{
  "Part1": "{\"Data1\":\"Data1\",\"Data2\":\"Data2\"}",
  "Part2": "{\"Text1\":\"Text1\",\"Text2\":\"Text2\"}"
}
```

I understand that there's text manipulation methods I can use to get this to work, but I'm hoping for a clean SQL > JSON statement.

I'm currently working on `SQL Server 2016` but I can if necessary get a `2017` or `2019` server.  Not sure if later SQL handles this better or if it's just my query that needs optimisation.

Edit: My desired output is:

```
{
  "Part1": {
      "Data1": "Data1",
      "Data2": "Data2"
    },
  "Part2": {
      "Text1": "Text1",
      "Text2": "Text2"
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the accepted answer of [FOR JSON PATH. how to not use escape characters](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9d74ecc3-9c76-4cbf-af11-304aa02d95e6/for-json-path-how-to-not-use-escape-characters?forum=SQLServer2016Preview) on SQL Server's forum on MSDN:

> FOR JSON will escape any text unless if it is generated as JSON result by some JSON function/query. In your example, FOR JSON cannot know do you really want raw JSON or you are just sending some free text that looks like JSON.
>
> Properly defined JSON is generated with FOR JSON (unless if it has WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER option) or JSON_QUERY. If you wrap your JSON literal with JSON_QUERY it will not be escaped.

This answer got me to try the following code:

```
DECLARE @Json nvarchar(max) = 
(
    SELECT
     JSON_QUERY((
        SELECT 'Data1' AS [Data1], 'Data2' AS [Data2]

        FOR JSON PATH
        , INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
        , WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
    )) AS [Part1]
    ,
    JSON_QUERY((
        SELECT 'Text1' AS [Text1], 'Text2' AS [Text2]

        FOR JSON PATH
        , INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
        , WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
    )) AS [Part2]

    FOR JSON PATH
    , WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
);

SELECT @Json;
```

As as it turns out - this is working like a charm. Results:

```
{
    "Part1": {
        "Data1": "Data1",
        "Data2": "Data2"
    },
    "Part2": {
        "Text1": "Text1",
        "Text2": "Text2"
    }
}
```

[<kbd>DB<>Fiddle</kbd>](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=dc00463edd9229d2e5e9cea4fb74463f)

---

**Update**
Look what I found buried in [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-modify-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#example---modify-a-json-object):

> To avoid automatic escaping, provide newValue by using the JSON_QUERY function. JSON_MODIFY knows that the value returned by JSON_MODIFY is properly formatted JSON, so it doesn't escape the value.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, I came up with something similar which is why I mentioned I know I can use text minipulation but I'll only look further at that route as a last resort.  I'm convinced it's either a bug (and therefore hopefully fixed in a newer version) or I'm doing something wrong (the most likely issue).

Comment: After some more digging I came up with a sql -> Json answer, no string manipulation. edited my answer completely.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, The above is fine (+1 from my side). The `FOR JSON` route doesn't look finished yet, more like a *beta*... Using the *without_array_wrapper* hint, the JSON is no more returned as a real JSON, but as a string which needs escaping. Using `JSON_QUERY()` is the appropriate way to tell the engine, that the string is to be taken as JSON expression. I hope, that a future version will introduce a real JSON type, not just a fancy engine wrapping *nvarchar(max)*...

Comment: Just FYI, stumbled upon a part of the official documentation explaining the `json_query` effect on json escape. updated my answer for future readers.