# SQL generate JSON without square brackets

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have this query:

```
SELECT 
    'Ball' AS title, 'Blue' AS color, 
    (SELECT '1' AS Opt1, '2' AS Opt2 
     FOR JSON PATH) AS 'Options'
FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('product')
```

And I get this JSON which is quite good but I can't have brackets after `product` (marked)

```
{"product": 
[  <======
{
 "title": "Ball",
 "color": "Blue",
 "Options": [{"Opt1": "1","Opt2": "2"}]
}
]  <======
}
```

In other words I need this:

```
{"product": 
{
 "title": "Ball",
 "color": "Blue",
 "Options": [{"Opt1": "1","Opt2": "2"}]
}
}
```

I can't use the `WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER` option because I already use `ROOT` option.
What should I do to remove these square brackets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very close to Greg Low's answer, but wrapping the inner select with `json_query` to avoid automatic escape (which happens because the option `without_array_wrapper` is used):

```
SELECT JSON_QUERY((
    SELECT 'Ball' AS title, 
           'Blue' AS color, (
                select '1' AS Opt1, 
                       '2' AS Opt2 
                FOR JSON PATH
           ) as Options
    FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
    )) AS Product
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER;
```

This gives you the desired result -

```
{
  "Product": {
    "title": "Ball",
    "color": "Blue",
    "Options": [
      {
        "Opt1": "1",
        "Opt2": "2"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Why is it necessary to have double brackets after the first SELECT?

Comment: One belongs to the `json_query` function, the other one encapsulates the select statement, meaning the value returned from the select statement goes as a parameter to the `json_query` function. Without the inner parenthesis you'll get a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?

```
SELECT (SELECT 'Ball' AS title, 
               'Blue' AS color, 
               (select '1' AS Opt1, '2' AS Opt2 FOR JSON PATH) as 'Options'
        FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER) AS Product
        FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER;
```

Comment: This is close but it will escape the inner json. To avoid automatic escape, [read my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57553177/3094533)